# SQL selecting through a join table with a where or clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

two tables:

tasks - id, creator_id (rest not relevant)

tag_tasks - tag_id, task_id

I want to grab tasks through tag_tasks via an array of tag ids, BUT also grab tasks that have a certain creator_id.

Here is the statement I am executing currently (that is not working):

```
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.content
FROM  `tasks` 
JOIN tag_tasks ON tasks.id = tag_tasks.task_id
WHERE (
  `tag_tasks`.`tag_id` 
  IN (1,2,3)
)
OR tasks.creator_id =1
GROUP BY tasks.id
ORDER BY  `tasks`.`id` DESC
```

This will return any tasks through the tag_tasks table, but ignores tasks that don't have a record in my join table.

What i'd like is a single query that would do this:

```
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.content
    FROM  `tasks` 
    JOIN tag_tasks ON tasks.id = tag_tasks.task_id
    WHERE (
      `tag_tasks`.`tag_id` 
      IN (1,2,3)
    )
    GROUP BY tasks.id
    ORDER BY  `tasks`.`id` DESC;
```

AND

```
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.content
FROM tasks
WHERE tasks.creator_id =1
GROUP BY tasks.id
ORDER BY  `tasks`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A regular join will work.  You want to change the condition to an `or`:

```
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.content
    FROM  `tasks` left outer join
          tag_tasks
          ON tasks.id = tag_tasks.task_id
    where `tag_tasks`.`tag_id` IN (1,2,3) or tasks.creator_id = 1
    GROUP BY tasks.id
    ORDER BY  `tasks`.`id` DESC;
```

That gets the full list.  You can limit this to 30 overall.  Do you really want all of the "1, 2, 3" tags along with only 30 of the others from creator 1, as implied by the last two queries (but not actually mentioned in the question)?

EDIT:

As I look at the query, I see you are retrieving information only at the task level.  If you are looking for asks that have a 1, 2, or 3 tag or are created by 1, I would recommend using the having clause:

```
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.content
    FROM  `tasks` left outer join
          tag_tasks
          ON tasks.id = tag_tasks.task_id
    GROUP BY tasks.id
    having tasks.creator_id = 1 or sum(tag_id in (1, 2, 3)) > 0
    ORDER BY  `tasks`.`id` DESC;
```

This makes it more flexible in the event that you want to modify the condition.  For instance, if you wanted all the tags or at least two of them.

Comment: The first query does not return tasks WHERE creator_id = 1, only those tasks that have a tag_task record (my original problem). The second query raises an error: "Unknown column 'tasks.creator_id' in 'having clause'". Either way, I will edit my question with my solution, and thank you for informing me about having, which I'll have to look up.

Comment: @Squadrons . . . Those problems are fixed using `left outer join` (the `or`s ignore `NULL` values).  Although you do say "no match" in the question, I confused myself and wasn't sure if that meant no matching tag records at all or no tags with ids 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Regardless, I had a feeling the type of join was what was causing me problems. I'll be reading up on joins to better educate myself. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

please use this:

```
SELECT tasks.id, tasks.content
FROM  `tasks` 
JOIN tag_tasks ON tasks.id = tag_tasks.task_id
WHERE (
  `tag_tasks`.`tag_id` 
  IN (1,2,3) 
  OR tasks.creator_id =1
)
GROUP BY tasks.id
ORDER BY  `tasks`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: Same problem as above - this query returns only those tasks which have a linking table (tag_tasks) record, not those tasks AND tasks that have a creator_id of 1

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query that solved my problem. I just needed to create a LEFT JOIN instead of a JOIN clause:

```
SELECT tasks.* 
FROM `tasks` 
LEFT JOIN tag_tasks on tasks.id = tag_tasks.task_id 
WHERE (tag_tasks.tag_id IN (517) OR creator_id = 658) 
GROUP BY tasks.id 
ORDER BY tasks.created_at DESC
```